# Radar chart for desktop java application

Tags: java, charts, radar-chart

Could you advise some library to create a radar chart in my desktop java application?

thanks

Comment: Oh, ok. I googled for that and looked on the charts4j, but it uses an network communication to work. I can't find a radar chart in the JFreeChart demo page. After that I decided to post a question here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems `JFreeChart` offers a [`SpiderWebPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/SpiderWebPlot.html).  The [images for which](http://www.google.com/search?q=SpiderWebPlot+jfreechart&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=05r&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&prmd=imvnsfd&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=W3BTT9qxKu6XiQez8-i5BQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CAwQ_AUoAQ&biw=1078&bih=974) look like a radar chart.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like what i need. Thanks

Comment: +1 Filed under _miscellaneous_ in the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).

Comment: @trashgod  (sighs) So many charts, so little screen acreage. Thanks for the empowered search. :)